# Make PHP url with unique format

Tags: php, html, url, hyperlink

I am confused about how to go to a specific url after I click a button,

I made button that goes to a page containing a form (php file) so it will go to **form.php**

> www.domain.com/form.php

Because there are many types of forms I want to make it simple and populate the page with another file. I remember that I learned something like this so I can call one php file into another file.

> www.domain.com/form.php?package=standard

Is there any link or tutorial that I can follow to help me do this?

Thanks

Comment: You are going on the right way. Just pass the package parameter in url (?package=standard) and check the value of parameter (using if....else) and based on the value render the specific form. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

put your button design to an a tag like this:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/form.php?package=standard" class="btn btn-primary">Im a button</a>
```

clicking the button will now redirect you to the link. if you want to redirect in a new tab
put target="_blank" on your a tag like this:

```
 <a href="www.domain.com/form.php?package=standard" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Im a button</a>
```

but if you want to retain the button tag, call the link using javascript or jquery.